# Spring websockets: message not published

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I use Spring WebSockets with STOMP and SockJS for frontend. It works FINE but I have another difficulty.

This is backend code:

```
 @MessageMapping("/showAccountlist")
 @SendTo("/topic/accounts")
 public Account createPublishAccount(String name) throws Exception {

     return new Account(name);
 }
```

And this is front end code, which works FINE, all messages gets published to all clients.

```
 stompClient.send("/app/showAccountlist", {}, name);
```

BUT when I call my backend method **from** my java backend, with method name

```
createPublishAccount("Carlos");
```

Seems like messages does not get published. Any solution? Or this is not how it meant to work and it only works when it is triggered via SockJS?

This is my webconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/showAccountlist").withSockJS();
}
```

}

Comment: Is class with createPublishAccount method instantiated by Spring?

Comment: Seems like it's impossible to send message by calling @SendTo annotated method. Does it work using `SimpMessagingTemplate` ?

Comment: Sure. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send

Comment: @ Jakub Bibro thanks SimpMessagingTemplate  works. If you can update your answer in a descriptive way and with a code sample. I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like it's impossible to send message by calling @SendTo annotated method.

Spring recommanded way of sending messages is to use `SimpMessagingTemplate`. It is possible to have desination as an argument (in your case `/topic/accounts`) for example in `convertAndSendToUser` method (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html).

Please see excerpt from Spring documentation 
(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send):

> What if you want to send messages to connected clients from any part of the application? Any application component can send messages to the "brokerChannel". The easiest way to do that is to have a SimpMessagingTemplate injected, and use it to send messages. Typically it should be easy to have it injected by type, for example:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/greetings", method=POST)
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        String text = "[" + getTimestamp() + "]:" + greeting;
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, bounty will also be accepted in 20 hours. I have a question here though. the method "convertAndSend" also accepts parameter "user", to send a message to specific user. but couldnt figure out how to use this. what is a user here? I need to update the balance info on client side, if a certain account received money.

Comment: This applies to Principal name from spring security. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-authentication for more details. So spring, based on queue name and principal name,  translates it to specific queue name and message will be delivered to certain user.

Comment: my app dont use authentication, can I still use spring security in this case? maybe I silently need to generate a random username on client-side everytime a websocket connection is made?

Comment: Yes, you can add spring security to your project because you need to ensure that user only receives its own messages. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination. "Spring’s STOMP WebSocket support expects users to have been authenticated already via HTTP". But afair, there is an option to distinguish user by websocket session somehow. A lot depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: But you could for example generate some user identification on front-end site, subscribe to _user_ queue and use it later to send messages to that user.

Comment: thanks I solved the problem by simply /topic/balance/${pageContext.session.id} and keeping sessions ids attached to all accounts